# how to get transaction id with srmklive/paypal

Tags: laravel, paypal-sandbox

I am using srmklive/paypal for paypal payment gateway. Payment is working fine. But I am not getting any transaction id.

My controller is:

```
public function paymentPaypalSuccess(Request $request, $encrypted_video_id)
    {
        $video_id = Crypt::decrypt($encrypted_video_id);
        $provider = new PayPalClient;
        $provider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
        $provider->getAccessToken();
        $response = $provider->capturePaymentOrder($request['token']);
        if (isset($response['status']) && $response['status'] == 'COMPLETED') {
            if(isset($video_id) && !empty($video_id))
            {
                $save_transaction = new Transcation();
                $save_transaction->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $save_transaction->item_type = 'video';
                $save_transaction->item_id = $video_id;
                $save_transaction->amount = $response['purchase_units'][0]['payments']['captures'][0]['amount']['value'];
                $save_transaction->transaction_id = $response['id'];
                $save_transaction->transaction_type = 'paypal';
                $save_transaction->is_payment_done = 1;
                $save_transaction->save();
            }
            $message = 'Your transaction is completed successfully!';
            $transaction_id = $response['id'];
            return view('frontend.payment.success_payment',compact('message','transaction_id'));
        } else {
            return view('frontend.payment.error_payment');
        }
    }
```

In above code, the $response['id'] is different from the transaction section in the seller account. I went through with the documentation of the package. But I didn't get any transaction method or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

That was my mistake.
I had to check the response as well.
I got the transaction id by:

$response['purchase_units'][0]['payments']['captures'][0]['id']

This is the correct id.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).